VUE 3 y Symfony 7. URL se actualiza pero la vista no
Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Vue3 (composition API) y Symfony7. Instalé vue-router.
Problema: Cuando le doy al botón que me lleva a la página de sketchbook, la url se actualiza, pero no la vista.
Tengo este menu.vue donde simplemente tengo un botón, al hacer click sobre el botón me lleva a la vista sketchbook.vue:
 <script setup>
 import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
 import menu from '../../json/menu.json'

 const router = useRouter()
 const route = useRoute()

 function navigateToSketchbookView() {
  router.push({ name: 'Sketchbook' })
 }
 </script>

 <template>
  <div>
    <button @click="navigateToSketchbookView">click</button>
  </div>
 </template>

Este es mi App.js donde instancio vue:
import './styles/app.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './components/App.vue'
import router from './router.js'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')

Este es mi router.js dónde defino mis rutas:
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import App from './components/App.vue'
import SketchbookView from './components/views/SketchbookView.vue';

const routes = [
 { path: '/', component: App, name: 'Home' },
 { path: '/sketchbook', component: SketchbookView, name: 'Sketchbook' }
]

const router = createRouter({
 history: createWebHistory(),
 routes 
})

export default router

Por la parte de Back, tengo un HomeController.php que renderiza base.html.twig :
<?php
 namespace App\Controller;

 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
 use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

 class HomeController extends AbstractController
  {
    #[Route('/')]
    public function number(): Response
    {
      return $this->render('base.html.twig');
    }    
 }

Y un SketchbookController.php que renderiza sketchbook.html.twig:
<?php
 namespace App\Controller;

 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
 use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

 class SketchbookController extends AbstractController
  {
    #[Route('/sketchbook')]
    public function number(): Response
  {
    return $this->render('sketchbook.html.twig');
  }
 }


Hola Inca, me da la sensación que estas mezclando tecnologías ya que vue-router sirve para crear SPA y en PHP estas creando las mismas rutas pero no como API para recuperar datos.
